# Reading prefetch file content

Tags: python, prefetch

I'm using python prefetch view to read the prefetch files' content.
But the tool show something like volume guid or anything instead of volume letter
[image]

Is there any correct way to convert "\VOLUME{01d820ac778f54ef-ba78425f}" to drive letter?
Do it correctly and logically instead of trying to randomly replace characters like "C:" or "D:"

Comment: My guess i you can find this correspndence somewhere in the Windows registry.

Comment: What is "python prefetch view"? Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Lol, I have found the solution to solve my problem

It is using this code to get details of the volumes (driver serial and driver letter)

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
Drivers_Information = []
def to_hex(val, nbits):
  return hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits)).lstrip('0x')

for i in c.Win32_Volume():
    Drivers_Information.append(("Driver_serial\\"+str(to_hex(i.SerialNumber,32)).replace("0x","")+"\\",i.Caption))
```

And compare with the volume serial number in the "volume information" then I know exactly which driver letter represented by the \VOLUME{01d820ac778f54ef-ba78425f}

If you have another better solution, pls let me know.